# How to change the eclipse hono's database with postgresql

Tags: eclipse-hono

I am new to Eclipse Hono. I have installed eclipse hono, using Helm chart and kubernetes(https://www.eclipse.org/hono/docs/getting-started), it is up and running and I am sending the messages from MQTT with AMQP Network.
Here are my some doubts and questions.

1. Where all the messages are get storing, and how to get access and see the data.
2. How to change the Hono's database to postgresql
3. Where are the Eclipse Hono files are stored.

Answer (score 1):

*Where all the massages are get storing, and how to get access and see the data.*

The messages are not stored by the Hono. Hono just forwards the messages from the device to the back end application. In order to get the message send by the device you have to connect to the AMQP (Kafka) network. For test purposes there is Hono command line client that acts as application. It could be downloaded from https://www.eclipse.org/hono/downloads

*How to change the Hono's database to postgresql*

You could check the configuration at https://www.eclipse.org/hono/docs/admin-guide/jdbc-device-registry-config/.    The helm chart has properties to configure external jdbc database. Basically you need deviceRegistryExample.type=jdbc and check the values for hono.jdbcBasedDeviceRegistry at https://github.com/eclipse/packages/blob/master/charts/hono/values.yaml. The PotgresSQL itself has to be deployed externally.

*Where are the Eclipse Hono files are stored.*

The source code is located at https://github.com/eclipse-hono/hono. Is that what you are you looking for?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have downloaded the client and tested out it's working fine with internally. But I am sending the IoT sensor data from eclipse kura  using MQTT adapter,  to a tenant. and I have downloaded the postgresql JDBC jar file. Now I want to change the classpath of the Hono to store the data in postgres. Where will be the .yaml file in my local computer.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve.

It is not needed to add JDBC driver jar to the classpath in order to use Hono JDBC Device Registry with PostgreSQL. The Hono JDBC Device Registry uses internally https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/jdbc/JDBCClient.html. This Vertx JDBC client can connect to any JDBC compliant database.
As I wrote before you only need to configure the helm chart and to deploy the database server (if it is not running already).